# Getting collision detection in Pygames

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am writing a game in Pygame, I want to get collision detection.
The aim is when a object hits another, the target object disappears. I want to avoid having classes and just have my code class less for now, in on script. This makes it difficult to get collision detection because the Rect method in Pygame is called on by an object(class).

The logic I want to achieve is:

1. object hits a target object
2. target object disappears.

is there an easy way to achieve this?(with minimal code possible)

Comment: If you're avoiding classes, what data structure(s) are you using to keep track of your "objects" and "targets"? It's difficult to answer your question without some sample code.

Comment: For now, I just have one copy of each, but in time i would like to have a list for the targets

Comment: i said a list containing targets

Comment: Sigh...what's a target consist of?

Answer (score 0):

Each rectangle can be defined by two points (lower left and upper right corners).

Without using classes, you could write a function that checks for collision between two rectangles.

The function needs following parameters: the lower left of rectangle A and B, and the upper right coordinates of rectangle A and B.

Also: check out "bounding box collision detection"...